# SQL query isn't resulting in filled table

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table

I think there is probably something wrong with my code, but I can not find it. My connection is good, but my tables in HTML isn't filling with the result. The query also works when I run it in phpMyAdmin. Here is my code. (And yes I know it's not the best, but it is only for a simple school project and I just need it to work..)

```
   $bnavn = $_COOKIE['bnavn'];

   //Steg 2: Kjør en SQL-spørring mot databasen
   $sql = 'SELECT p_bnavn, p_fnavn, p_enavn, p_adresse, p_saldo, p_bil, p_lånt FROM bk_profil WHERE p_bnavn = "' . $bnavn . '"';
   $resultat = mysqli_query($tilkobling, $sql);

   while ($rad = $resultat->fetch_assoc() ) {

     $fnavn = $rad['p_fnavn'];
     $enavn = $rad['p_enavn'];
     $adresse = $rad['p_adresse'];
     $saldo = $rad['p_saldo'];
     $bil = $rad['p_bil'];
     $lånt = $rad['p_lånt'];

     ?>
     <?php
     echo "<tr>";

     echo "<td>$bnavn</td>";

     echo "<td>$fnavn</td>";

     echo "<td>$enavn</td>";

     echo "<td>$adresse</td>";

     echo "<td>$saldo</td>";

     echo "<td>$bil</td>";

     echo "<td>$lånt</td>";

     echo "</tr>";

   }
```

Comment: can you see the empty table itself? I did not see `<table> </table>`

Comment: Yes, it is in the html code, outside of the php. The <th>name</th> is showing

Comment: was `$resultat` successful?

Comment: What's the result of this SQL when you run it by hand?

Comment: You really should be reporting mysqli errors: `$resultat = mysqli_query($tilkobling, $sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);`

Comment: `p_lånt` looks would look suspicious to me depending on your table encoding.